# Using regex and sed command to substitute ' *' pointers in C++ code is not working

Tags: c++, regex, ubuntu, sed

I'm a rookie programmer dealing with a C++ code that I should review and study. One of the basic task I'm with is to change the pointers notification like this:

```
char *name;
```

to this convention:

```
char* name;
```

Since my OS is Ubuntu 13.10, I thought that regex could do the job. I studied it a bit and tried different variations of a command like this:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/(?<=\w)\s\*(?!\s)/\* /g' {} \;
```

That is intended to be read as: find in string an alphanumeric, then matches with whitespace followed by asterisk, when is followed by not-a-whitespace, and replace with asterisk and whitespace. I understand that for substitution \s cannot be used, that look ahead/behind will not enter in the match, so I played a bit with command with little success. 
I tried it first with Eclipse IDE 'find' menu, and regular expression seems to be properly build since it's really finding what I expect. But when I try the command, it's not changing the lines as expected, in fact they stand still the same, untouched.

I was also trying a narrower case of the above, i.e. to change casting to pointer like this:

```
(char *) another_name
```

into this

```
(char*) another_name
```

using this command line:

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/(?<=\w)\s\*(?=\))/\*/g' {} \;
```

But seems that regex engine is not recognizing the escaped parenthesis, since it gives me "sed: -e expression #1, char 25: Unmatched ) or )".

Now I'm banging my head to the wall trying to figure out which the correct way to handle this: why the substitution is not working as expected, and why the same command using isntead an escaped parenthesis inside the positive look behind is not recognized?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion you can give.

Comment: Does sed support lookaheads/lookbehinds? (I think the answer is no)

Comment: if you're using eclipse, you can also use code formatter to achieve the result..

Comment: You can use `-E` parameter to support extended regex.

Comment: @Velthune - I'll check the code formatter, maybe is the safest way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) does not support lookaround assertions, enable the `-r` flag and use extended regular expressions:

```
sed -i -r 's/(\w+)\s*\*(\w)/\1\* \2/g'
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/QFuhfw)

In Perl you can use lookaround assertions:

```
perl -i -pe 's/(?<=\w)\s*\*(?=\w)/\* /g'
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/avk5q4)

Comment: I didn't know that exception for sed command. BTW, your suggestion can get wrong matches when comments like this are encountered: 
/*
 * blah blah blah
 *
 */

That's the reason why the look ahead/behind requirement...

Comment: Thanks for the update, it still matches with this line: 
/* this is a comment */
And that would uncomment the sentence

Comment: @hwnd that's working better, and the mechanism underlying it (the backreference) is something I didn't thought about. So I consider it an acceptable answer to question - still keeping in mind that safe programming should avoid intrusive commands like regex. Thus I marked positively your kind help.

Comment: To anyone interested in the the topic, even Eclipse suffers of the same problem (even if for sed is a characteristic in order not to lose its stream editor identity according to this: [link](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/editor-faq/sed/) - Thanks again hwnd). 
In fact here's the related Eclipse bug tracker, still not implemented: [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=109481)

Answer (score 0):

"a rookie programmer dealing with a C++ code" probably shouldn't be automating this. Have you thought about the cases of `*` used for multiplication

```
name * another_name
```

or dereference?

```
Type t = *it;
```

You seem to think C++ casts live inside round brackets

```
(char*) name
```

where in fact they usualy appear inside angle ones

```
static_cast<char*>(name)
```

*etc*....

You might be better of doing this one by hand to better learn what you're dealing with.

Comment: Would it really matter for these cases you're mentioning, if a simple left side blank appearing before `*` should be removed?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the whole point of this exercise seems to be about code beautification so just assuming, yes, *that* would really matter.

Comment: using a regex to <bold>find</bold> the candidates, and later to verify the edits, could still be useful, but I find that automated changes to code are risky for an experienced programmer (me).

Comment: I understand your point, which is absolutely correct, but doing it by hand would take a huge amount of time. Probably I should go though Eclipse tools to handle it safely.